# Who is your favorite European Windows web host provider?

Tags: sql-server-2005, web-hosting, asp-classic, isapi

Who is your favorite European Windows web host provider?

The provider must support:

- 1 Dedicated IP address
- ISAPI Rewrite
- SQL Server 2005
- Classic ASP
- ASP JPEG

Comment: what do you mean by best windows web host provider... That don't make any sense. Be more specific in your question!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use windows hosting, but try with ovh.com

They are located in france, but have datacenters all over europe.

Comment: OVH also support windows web language framework (asp.net or c# for exemple)

Answer (score 0):

Look into www.centron.de. They're located in Germany and I use them for my website since years. I rent a box from them which serves over 4.5 million page views a month and I am having no issues. Prices are very reasonable.